# How to implement an MVC Model that doesn't link directly to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement a view that displays information from a database that has been modified just before displaying.  For example, I am trying to add markup labor and hardware costs to give a final price.  the problem is I can't use a foreach loop to display it in the view because it is a `List`, and I am having trouble declaring it as an `IEnumerable` because it won't let me use the `Add()` function.  Here is my model,

```
namespace Myname.Models{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Pricing
{
    public List<int> ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Manufac { get; set; }
    public List<string> Model { get; set; }
    public List<string> Service { get; set; }
    public List<string> Type { get; set; }
    public List<int> Price { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my index method in my controller,

```
 private WTEntities db = new WTEntities();

    // GET: /JobInformation/
    [Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Pricing prices = new Pricing();
        prices.ID = new List<int>();
        prices.Manufac = new List<string>();
        prices.Model = new List<string>();
        prices.Price = new List<int>();
        prices.Service = new List<string>();

        foreach(var item in db.JobInformations)
        {
            prices.ID.Add(item.ID);
            prices.Manufac.Add(item.Manufac);
            prices.Model.Add(item.Model);
            prices.Service.Add(item.Service);
            prices.Price.Add(((int)item.MarkupCostCents + (int)item.LaborCostCents + (int)item.HardwareCostCents) / 100);
        }
        return View(prices);
    }
```

and here is my view,

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufac)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Service)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Does the database already exist where `Pricing` is defined or are you designing from scratch?

Comment: @Inanikian Pricing is a model from scratch, which is pulling only some of the values from another database model.  The other model lists the markup cost, labor cost, etc. but I'm trying to make a model from scratch that will have a new member called Price, that is calculated from those values, so Price is never stored in a database, just calculated on the fly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've designed your model incorrectly for what you're trying to accomplish.

You should create a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public class Pricing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Manufac { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var prices = new List<Pricing>();

foreach(var item in db.JobInformations)
{
    var price = new Pricing();
    price.ID = item.ID;
    price.Manufac = item.Manufac;
    price.Model = item.Model;
    price.Service = item.Service;
    price.Price = ((int)item.MarkupCostCents + (int)item.LaborCostCents + (int)item.HardwareCostCents) / 100;

    prices.Add( price );
}

return View(prices);
```

Now in your view you can do exactly what you've already written (just be sure to change the @model declaration to List).

Comment: @Crag W. Ok, thanks, that makes sense, the only problem now is that the line "Pricing prices = new List<Pricing>();" is trying to create a list, when the model class isn't a list, so I get an error.  Error 3 'Myname.Models.Pricing' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Myname.Models.Pricing' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: the only change I had to make was **List<Pricing>** prices = new List<Pricing>();  got it, thanks!

Comment: Oops. I'll update the original post. That's the problem with SO not actually compiling the code. :-)